# how to mysql group by date multiple left join

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have the following schema:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd3a4/1
I would like to 
    group by date() and add where user_id = ?..
per day and count the results per day.
required result Day|TotalRequests|TotalOrders

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. But also add all necessary info into the question. Links break, especially SQLFiddle. And we want posts being useful to future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you could have an order on Day 1, and a request on Day 8, you may have entries on one side but not the other.  To qualifify your needs, I would do a UNION of all orders and requests individually by date.  Then roll those values up.  The inner Pre-Aggregate result query is where the WHERE clause per user would be applied.  The pre-aggregate query also has a recSource column to indicate where the record originated from as 'O' from orders and 'R' from requests, so the roll-up knows which column to store the total count respectively.

```
select
      preAgg.recDate,
      SUM( case when preAgg.recSource = 'O' then preAgg.recCount else 0 end ) as OrderCount,
      SUM( case when preAgg.recSource = 'R' then preAgg.recCount else 0 end ) as RequestCount
   from
      ( select
              date(o.created_at) recDate,
              'O' as recSource,
              count(*) as recCount
           from
              orders o
           where
              o.user_id = 3
           group by
              date(o.created_at)
       UNION ALL
       select
              date(r.created_at) recDate,
              'R' as recSource,
              count(*) as recCount
           from
              requests r
           where
              r.user_id = 3
           group by
              date(r.created_at) ) preAgg
   group by
      preAgg.recDate
   order by 
      preAgg.recDate
```

For query optimization, I would ensure your order and request table both have have an index on ( user_id, created_at ).

[SQL Fiddle result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd3a4/34)

Comment: this is great didn't know this technique, how would  I add let's say a commissions_table and SUM(commissions.amount) per date(),in this case we won't be able to use UNION.

Comment: @dflow, same process, just add an ADDITIONAL... "UNION ALL", but have the same column / sum / group by context.  Set the recSource as "C" for Commission (just as an example). and change from COUNT(*) to SUM( commission.Amount ) as recCount, so it complies with the outer query expectation values.  And then add a final SUM( case/when ) for the commission recSource value = "C"

Comment: great, one more thing the commission.Amount is of decimal type so all the results are returned in decimal format, so it's counting 84.00 etc, how can I set the result column format?

Comment: @dflow, look into CAST( ... as integer ) for the other columns, but let the commission remain as decimal precision.

Comment: @dflow, also check out Help -> Tour for site etiquette.  Marking answers with checkbox indicates to others it has been solved so others don't waste time trying to answer... or helps those looking for similar issue what did work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT
DATE(o.created_at) AS Day
,COUNT(r.id) AS TotalRequests
,COUNT(o.id) AS TotalOrders 
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN
requests r ON
r.id = o.request_id
WHERE o.user_id = 3
GROUP BY DATE(r.created_at), DATE(o.created_at),o.user_id
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, how would I combine the result to Day | TotalRequests | TotalOrders